# Mono https authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: c#, encryption, https, xamarin, mono

I am trying to access a REST API located at an HTTPS address. I always get "authentication or decryption failure". I have already tried every different solution that I could find at both xamarin forums, Mono pages and Stack Overflow and no success at all. I've tried all changes to code for ignoring errors and I have tried importing certificates using mozroots and certmgr, importing for both user and machine in all of their different stores (CA, Trust and AddressBook).

I tried at both Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 and Xamarin Studio on Mac OS El Capitan.

I'm getting really frustrated for not being able to accomplish such a basic task as accessing a REST API.

I just need to access the following location: https://api.wearefero.com/api/v1/activity (it's okay if you get 401, as it needs token authentication and it got through the certificates check).

If you succeed on not getting an error please let me know what did you do (preferably paste your configs here).

Below you can find a basic TlsTest run output I always get.

Thanks a lot!

```
FAILED: #-2146233079
System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x4678ad8 + 0x000e3> in :0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x4678a30 + 0x0001f> in :0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x4676088 + 0x0019b> in :0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) <0x4679db0 + 0x00183> in :0 
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 (IAsyncResult r) <0x46797f8 + 0x000eb> in :0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x2d37aa0 + 0x00187> in :0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () <0x2d31eb8 + 0x0004c> in :0 
at TlsTest.GetWebPage (System.String url) <0x6d9fa8 + 0x00273> in :0 
at TlsTest.Main (System.String[] args) <0x6d61c8 + 0x00583> in :0
```

Comment: Which version of Mono? Run `mono --version` to check the output.

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3

Comment: I tried the link and it's returning a 404 error.  Run a communcations trace and tell us what you see.

Comment: Have you tried using ModernHTTPClient?  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26658

Comment: @Jason yes i did tried without success :( the certificate is from cloudflare, and someone else in the link you provided seems to be facing the same issue

Comment: @JohnPeters I've updated the url.

Comment: Seems that Mono doesn't support the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol.

Comment: @FernandoMano You shoudl probably put this as the answer. Having similiar issues with https://www.solidi.co/api/v1/ticker - Xamarin Forms WebRequest failes for it, but is fine for www.google.co.uk.

Comment: My bad. I've forgot to put the solution here. 

The solution adopted was that I had to install modernhttpclient in ALL projects involved, like core, iOS and Android. My mistake was that I was only installing the modernhttpclient on the core project.  

There is no explicit instruction on which project should have the modernhttpclient installed and since the calls were all implemented on core project I've installed modernhttpclient only on core. 

So install modernhttpclient in core AND in platform-specific projects.